# Invalid database exception not caught

Tags: flutter, sqlite

To open a local database in Flutter using the sqflite and sqflite_common_ffi packages I supply the path to the database to open it. It succeeds on a valid database file. I'm trying to catch exceptions, particularly "invalid database file". However, nothing is caught :

```
try {
    final database = openDatabase(
        databaseFile!.path!,
        version: 1,
    );
} on Exception catch (e) {
    log('Error');
}
```

Stack trace:

```
flutter: error SqfliteFfiException(sqlite_error: 26, , SqliteException(26): while selecting from statement, file is not a database, file is not a database (code 26)
  Causing statement: PRAGMA user_version}) DatabaseException(SqliteException(26): while selecting from statement, file is not a database, file is not a database (code 26)
  Causing statement: PRAGMA user_version) sql 'PRAGMA user_version' {details: {database: {path: C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\project\.gitattributes, id: 1, readOnly: false, singleInstance: true}}} during open, closing...
```

I've tried catching `Exceptions` and `DatabaseExceptions` but can't catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Because the openDatabase function is async, it needs to be awaited for the exception to be caught.

```
try {
    final database = await openDatabase(
        databaseFile!.path!,
        version: 1,
    );
} on Exception catch (e) {
    log('Error');
}
```